# Windows has triggered a breakpoint

Tags: c++, dll

I'm experiencing a problem while trying to use functions exported from my DLL.

I'm getting a message which states (sorry, but I couldn't upload an image):

> Windows has triggered a breakpoint in LibTester.exe.
>
> This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in LibTester.exe or any
> of the DLLs it has loaded.
>
> This may also be due to the user pressing F12 while LibTester.exe has focus.
>
> The output window may have more diagnostic information.

I have a Vector class, with overloaded assignment operator and some constructors:

```
Vector::Vector() : X(0.0f), Y(0.0f), Z(0.0f) { }
Vector::Vector(const Vector& vector) : X(vector.X), Y(vector.Y), Z(vector.Z) { }
Vector::Vector(float x, float y, float z) : X(x), Y(y), Z(z) { }
.
.
.
Vector& Vector::operator=(const Vector& rhs)
{
    this->X = rhs.X;
    this->Y = rhs.Y;
    this->Z = rhs.Z;

    return *this;
}
```

The problem only occurs when i'm attempting to assign an existing vector to a new vector
generated by the constructor:

```
Vector v1 = Vector();                  //Works
Vector v2 = Vector(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);  //Works
v1 = v2;                               //Works
v1 = Vector();                         //Fails
v1 = Vector(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);         //Fails
```

In case this is relevant, the Vector *struct* is derived from the *class* IPrintable:

```
class IPrintable
{
public: 
    ~IPrintable() 
    {
        if (this->m_pStr != NULL)
            delete[] this->m_pStr;
    }

    virtual char* ToString() = 0;   

protected:
    char* m_pStr;
};
```

Any one has a clue as to what could cause this behavior?

Comment: If that is the full code then the problem is that `m_pStr` is uninitialized but is referenced in the `IPrintable` destructor.

Comment: Textbook case of how `char*` strings and manual memory management are for very ugly people who want buggy code.

Comment: IPrintable needs a constructor, copy constructor and assignment operator to properly init and copy its m_pStr member.

Comment: Still can't reply properly, too bad...
Thank u all for answering, the cause was indeed that pointer.
I've added a constructor, copy constructor and assignment operator and it all worked out. hopefully I haven't introduced any more problems in the implementation.
And DeadMG: I don't like your answer, very impolite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that is the full definition of `IPrintable` the problem is that `m_pStr` is unitialised meaning there will be an incorrect invocation of `delete[]`.

This fails:

```
v1 = Vector();
```

because a temporary `Vector` is created and the faulty destructor is executed immediately. To correct initialise `m_pStr` or a better solution would be to use `std::string`. If you must use a `char*` then you must also implement a copy constructor and assignment operator or prevent copying (see [What is The Rule of Three?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)).